# yii2 framework message language

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2

As you know in Yii2 the core messages are available in 26 languages. I want to change yii core message language to display validation message in my language.

I added this line to my config file:

```
'language' => 'fa_IR',
```

and also added this lines:

```
'i18n'=>[
            ...
                'yii'=>[
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => "@vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages",
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'yii'=>'yii.php',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

but core message shown in English. I only want to use framework message available with Yii2. For example in this path **vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/fa_IR/yii.php**

What is the best solution for this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohhhh it's my mistake. Language code is **fa-IR** but I set it **fa_IR**.
I think all language code seperate by _ like **'sourceLanguage' => 'en_US',** but it's different.
Sorry all.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

Make sure you use translate method in your view files, like:

```
Yii::t('yii','Update')
```

Comment: I only want to use framework message available with Yii2. For example in this path vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/fa_IR/yii.php

Comment: Do you have any idea??

Answer (score -2):

```
'i18n' => [
    'translations' => [
        'common' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
            'basePath' => '@common/messages',
        ],
        'static' => [
            'class' => 'yii\mongodb\i18n\MongoDbMessageSource',
            'collection' => 'translation_static'
        ],
        'data' => [
            'class' => 'yii\mongodb\i18n\MongoDbMessageSource',
            'collection' => 'translation_data'
        ],
        'product' => [
            'class' => 'yii\mongodb\i18n\MongoDbMessageSource',
            'collection' => 'translation_product'
        ],
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\mongodb\i18n\MongoDbMessageSource',
            'collection' => 'translation_user'
        ],
    ],
],
```